# How to install win32clipboard for Python 2.6?

Tags: python, winapi, libraries

I downloaded amd64bit for Python 2.6 and installed it but when I use the python shell to import win32clipboard, it says "the specified module could not be found".

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20217/

I tried 32bit version but when I launch the installer, it complains that I don't have Python 2.6 and bails.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I downloaded amd64bit for Python 2.6 ...
>
> I tried 32bit version ...

You need the 64-bit version.

Comment: I downloaded the 64bit version but it didn't work. It installed fine but I can't import the library.